# leaderboard showing random category

Tags: ios, center, leaderboard

I'm having a weird issue with sandbox leaderboards on game center. I have two leaderboards with two seperate ID's aka categories. For some reason my first leaderboard button shows the correct leaderboard everytime but the second leaderboard button randomly picks between the two leaderboards. I'm sure my leaderboard categories are the correct name. I use leaderboardCategory and category to make sure ios5 and ios6 are handled correctly. It's almost as if i open one leaderboard than close it and open another quickly it doesn't load the correct leaderboard. ***Also when this issue happens the leaderboard title says "leaderboard"***

PS. does anyone know if its possible to have a GKLeaderBoardViewController that brings your to the leaderboard menu that shows all leaderboards as apposed to a specific leaderboard?

Thanks all.

EXAMPLE:

```
GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardController = [[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init];
if (leaderboardController != NULL)
{
    leaderboardController.leaderboardCategory = @"Bounce_2";
    leaderboardController.category = @"Bounce_2";
    leaderboardController.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime;
    leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController: leaderboardController animated: YES];
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Though I have to add that this happens only on ios 6. Do you have the same problem in non-sandbox (real) profile? By the way, if you pass nil to category you'll see list of categories both on ios5 and ios6.

Comment: I haven't taken in out of the sandbox yet, which could be the issue but i doubt it, if you find a solution please post an answer here! thanks

Comment: Hey guys I'm having the same issue: by passing the category to my  GKLeaderboardViewController instance, it sometimes shows the correct leaderboard, sometimes it's the default one. Any clue?

Comment: yet to try it out of the sandbox situation but apparently its a known bug thats been fixed in ios7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Erik Asmussen](https://devforums.apple.com/message/847879#847879) who reported the bug to Apple (id: 14206005), it has been fixed in iOS 7 (11A4400f).

The bug occurs when you use a leaderboards group, so you may want not to use one for now.